# Display instance Id's if the instance has no tag "Name"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have one requirement to display the instance id's which has no tag called `Name`.

I tried below cli commands to find but doesn't work for me.

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters Name="",Values=""

aws ec2 describe-tags
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to search for a tag that doesn't exist.

You would need to retrieve a list of all instances and then exclude ones that don't have the tag.

You could do it in Python like this:

```py
import boto3

ec2_resource = boto3.resource('ec2')

for instance in ec2_resource.instances.all():
    if 'Name' not in [tag['Key'] for tag in instance.tags]:
        print(instance.id)
```

Comment: Thank you so much John,. How can we stop the instances listed from above code.

Comment: @SreenivasReddy You can use [`stop_instances()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.stop_instances)

Comment: Yes correct but i am unable to apply stop_instances() method on "instnace.id" list directly  . Need to stop result list of all the instances which don't have tag "Name"

Comment: The simplest method is to just use `instance.stop()` inside the `if` statement.